# Convert HH:MM:ss string into datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, parsing

I am reading from excel file and save the content into database

one of the column contains length of video in this format

**HH:mm:ss**

I write this code so far

```
string time = oledbReader[6].ToString();
DateTime streamingTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, 
                             "HH:mm:ss",
                             System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I am getting error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I tried debug mode and I see the value :"30/12/1899 00:09:21" in the Variable **time**
when the value in the current execl column is:"00:09:21"

Where does the "30/12/1899" came from? Why is the string was not recognized as a valid DateTime?

Can I save only the format HH:mm:ss into sql server?

Comment: What is your culture?

Comment: It treats this field as a datetime value and formats it to only show time.

Comment: Use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure to hold a time value. A `DateTime` includes both a date and a time.

Comment: @HABO I think you understood the problem well ,please post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, easy hack as my comment above.

```
string time = oledbReader[6].ToString().Split(" ".ToCharArray())[1];
DateTime streamingTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

or you could parse it as it is...

```
DateTime streamingTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: ok that slove the error.Maybe I'm taking  wrong approach,I want in the future to have the Ability to sum the time of all videos ,what data type should I store in sql server in order to accomplish the task?

Comment: @baaroz - This depends on the version of SQL Server and is really another question -- you should post it as a question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't gave us any information about your `CultureInfo`, here with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx);

```
string time = "30/12/1899 00:09:21";
DateTime streamingTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(streamingTime);
```

Output will be;

```
12/30/1899 12:09:21 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/G6I81Q)</kbd>.

For more informations, check out [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: That is next level stuff dropping in a demo! +1.  You're making everyone else look bad! :)

Comment: His reader object is already a date time so parsing is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure to hold a time value. A `DateTime` includes both a date and a time.

Comment: can you give example how to hold only the HH:mm:ss from the excel row?can it be store in sql server under datetime datatype?

Comment: `TimeSpan.ParseExact` should be able to convert the last 8 characters of the value in string `time`. The SQL Server [`time`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) data type supports values less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that excel  not have time field and automatically convert time to date time field.
If course date is "empty" which means that it its a minimal date for excel - 30/12/1899

Moreover you don't have to invoke ToString methods because object is already a DateTime